# Rendering a partial using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

It seems simple but my partial is not rendered in a view(*dash.html.erb*) using ajax.

**routes.rb**

```
match "users/dash" => "users#dash"
```

**users controller**

```
def dash
     respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
   end
```

**dash.html.erb**

```
<div id= "mydiv">This view is not shown using ajax.</div>
```

**dash.js.erb**

```
$('#mydiv').html('<%= raw escape_javascript render("cart_payment") %>');
```

**My partial- _cart_payment.html.erb**

```
<p>This is a partial.</p>
```

UPDATE:

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

$.ajax({
  url: "users/dash",
  data: {  
  //params if needed

  }
});

</script>
```

Please note that I am calling- `users url` in browser because ajax is called from here. 
Is it not correct way or Am I missing something?

Comment: Whatever you're using to call dash has to have a data-remote="true" on it. ie a link or button or form

Comment: What happens if you call the `/controller_name/dash.js` in your browser?

Comment: @Magicmarkker- Sorry, I updated the question to include the call using ajax.

Comment: @davidb - Doing so, I am getting `$('#mydiv').html('<p>This is a partial.<\/p>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `dash` method remotely, it actually is executing the `$('#mydiv').html...` code. The problem is, your `index.html.erb` file has no `<div id='mydiv'>` to update in the first place.

If you replace your `index.html.erb` with this, it should work:

```
<div id='mydiv'></div>

<script type= "text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "users/dash",
    data: {  
    //params if needed
    }
  });
</script>
```